# Write an anonymous function validating email address

Tags: javascript, html, functional-programming, closure

> ## Problem statement
>
> Write an anonymous function which take email address as parameter and returns true/false after validating the input parameter.
>
> ## Objective
>
> This assignment will help you to master the following concepts:
>
> - function
> - closures
>
> ---

## Solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Anomymous function</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var result = (function(email_id){
                            var regpat = /^[a-zA-Z_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z_\-\.]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
                            return regpat.test(email_id);
                        })('xyz@gmail.com');
            document.write(result);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

1) Is this the corresponding solution?

2) Why `document.body.innerHTML = result;` does not work?

Answer (score 7):

As I already noted in your [other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114976/html-5-form-validation-and-form-handling), trying to validate email addresses correctly is an almost impossible task; there are a lot more [characters allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address) that you are assuming. Check out this [correct regex to validate addresses](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), which is quite unpractical.

This means that we can either be too strict or too lenient with our regex. For front-end validation, being too strict is not the right choice as people with valid email addresses will not be able to use your service.

Personally, I would check if there is an `@` in the string, and be done with it. It will catch common typos, there isn't much more you can do.

Later on, you could write two functions: `requiredEmailValidation` and `optionalEmailValidation`. The first just looks for an `@`, and doesn't allow a form to be submitted, the second checks for common typos (eg `.con` instead of `.com`, `gmai.com` instead of `gmail.com`, etc) and shows a warning.

**Misc**

- js variable names generally can't contain `-`. I'm surprised it's even working for you, it didn't for me with firefox or chrome.
- `regpat` isn't that great of a variable name; it's hard to read (`regexPattern` would be better), and contains few information (I can already see that it's a regex pattern). Something like `emailPattern` would be better (for such a short function, it's not that important, but if you write larger functions later on, naming becomes very important).

Answer (score 1):

1) looks like solution

2) it is not working because you are modifying dom when it is not loaded/ready yet, so move script tag after body (or inside) and it should work (or if you are using jquery use `$(function(){//your code}))`