# Login system with session using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, authentication, session, codeigniter

I implemented a login system, with session, using CodeIgniter.
If the session doesn't exist, redirect to login page.
Please review, and let me know what can be done to make it better.

**view (login.php)**

```
<body>
<?php echo form_open(base_url('verify'),['id' => 'loginForm', 'name' => 'loginForm', 'method' => 'post'])?>
    <div class="login wrap">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$">

      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

      <!-- <input type="button" value="Help!" /> -->
      <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </div>
<?php echo form_close("\n")?>
```

**verify.php (controller)**

```
class Verify extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(['form', 'url', 'security']);
    $this->load->library(['form_validation', 'encryption','session']);
    $this->load->model('User_Model');

}

public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim|xss_clean|callback_check_password');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/login');

    } else {
        redirect(base_url('dashboard/dash'));

    }
}

/*login process*/

public function check_password($password)
{
    $email = $this->input->input_stream('email', TRUE);
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);

    $result = $this->User_Model->login($email,$password);
    if($result != null){
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $sess_data = [
                'username' => $row->username,
                'user_id' => $row->id
            ];
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_data);
        }
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'invalid username and password');
        return FALSE;
    }
}


public function logout($page = 'login')
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect(base_url('login'),'refresh');
}
}
```

**Dashboard.php (dashboard controller)**

```
class Dashboard extends Check_Logged
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper(['form', 'url']);
    $this->load->library(['form_validation', 'encryption']);

}

public function index()
{
    if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
        redirect('dashboard/dash');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
}

public function login($page = 'login')
{
        if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
            redirect('dashboard/dash');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);

}

public function dash($page = 'dashboard')
{
    if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function logout($page = 'login')
{
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect(base_url('login'),'refresh');
}

public function portfolio($page = 'portfolio')
{
    if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function team($page = 'team')
{
    if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
    } else {
        redirect('login');
    }
}

}
```

**and check_Logged.php (controller)**

```
class Check_Logged extends CI_Controller
{
    public $logged = '';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(['form', 'url', 'security']);
        $this->load->library(['session', 'form_validation']);

        $this->logged = $this->session_check();
    }


    /*
     * Check the Session status
     * if session exist return true
     * else return false
     * */

    public function session_check()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != null)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- [Validating emails is hard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115103/write-an-anonymous-function-validating-email-address/115106#115106), and it's not a good idea to do it on your own with a regex. Here are a couple of valid email addresses you would not allow (there are a lot more): `"foo"@bar.com`, `foo+spam@bar.com`, `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{|}~@foo.com`. And even though it's so strict, it still lets through invalid addresses such as `foo@example.com]` (because the regex is actually broken).
- Use `type="email"` and let the browser handle the validation for you.
- Don't use sha256, it's [too fast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/hashing-passwords-in-php/104826#104826). Use bcrypt or similar instead.
- I wouldn't call `xss_clean` on user input. XSS should be prevented when printing data, not when receiving it. This is especially important for passwords, as `xss_clean` will weaken some passwords - possibly considerably.
- Your controllers aren't named all that well. What does `verify` verify? and does it only verify? `Check_Logged` could also be better named. Maybe `BaseAdminController` or something.
- all your methods are public, even though quite a lot of them could be private, making your classes more complicated than they need to be.
- Having to check if the user is logged in in each of the admin controller methods seems annoying, and could easily be forgotten. I would handle that case in the base controller `Check_Logged`, and then show the login page.
- You handle the not-logged-in case differently in different methods, without any apparent reason. Sometimes it's `$this->load->view('admin/login');`, sometimes `redirect('login');`, or `redirect(base_url('login'),'refresh');`. If there is a reason for the difference, I would comment on it. Otherwise, handle the same thing the same way to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems weird that in `check_password` the login would return multiple rows. I would expect only one user to be associated with a particular emails/password login.
2. In your controller you have duplicated this code three times:

   > ```
   > if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
   >     $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
   > } else {
   >     redirect('login');
   > }
   > ```

   This should be extracted into a single common function which is called by each of the controller actions.
3. This seems weird:

   > ```
   > if ($this->logged === TRUE) {
   >     redirect('dashboard/dash');
   > } else {
   >     $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
   > }
   > $this->load->view('admin/'.$page);
   > ```

   So if the user is not logged in you load the view and then you load the view again unconditionally?
4. I'm not PHP expert but I'm pretty sure `session_check` can be condensed into

   ```
   return $this->session->userdata('logged_in') != null;
   ```
5. `logged` is not a very good name for the property which seems to indicate whether or not the user is logged in. `is_logged_in` seems to be more expressive.