# Parsing "mailto:"

Tags: javascript, parsing, regex, email, url

Can you help me to review my "mailto:"-parsing function ?

Since I'm trying to write less code, that is as simple as possible.

I'm not sure there if there is some bug or better solution.

```
var href = 'mailto:hello@world.com?subject=My+Subject&body=My+Body';

function getMailto(s) {
    var r = {};
    var email = s.match(/mailto:([^\?]*)/);
            email = email[1]?email[1]:false;
  var subject = s.match(/subject=([^&]+)/);
            subject = subject?subject[1].replace(/\+/g,' '):false;
    var body = s.match(/body=([^&]+)/);
            body = body?body[1].replace(/\+/g,' '):false;

  if(email) {r['email'] = email;}
  if(subject) {r['subject'] = subject;}
  if(body) {r['body'] = body;}

  return r;
}

console.log(getMailto(href));
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/sq26m7eq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Im not sure there is some bug or better solution.

Like @Domenic said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560597), parsing URLs is hard, and it's nearly impossible to do it correctly with regexes. Email addresses are also [quite complex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115103/).

If your function is good enough really depends on your use-case. Most of the bugs described below may not apply, but I would at least fix the first one, which leads to problems with some valid email addresses.

Bugs:

- `?` is a valid character for the local part of an email address, but `mailto:hel?lo@world.com?subject=My+Subject&body=My+Body` breaks your script.
- You decode some URL encoded characters (the `+`), but not the rest, which seems odd. I would URL decode all characters. Otherwise, you can't have certain characters in your subject/body. Eg: `subject=Coffee&Cookies?` doesn't work, and `subject=Coffee%26Cookies?` isn't properly formatted (while `subject=Coffee+Cookies?` would be properly formatted, which is inconsistent)
- The order of arguments does not matter for URLs. But it does matter for your script, in some corner-cases: `mailto:hello@world.com?body=Hi+there+subject=Something&subject=My+Subject`
- your script breaks on invalid input such as `hello@world.com?body=b&subject=s`

**Misc**

- Your indentation is off.
- `r` and `s` aren't great variable names.
- more spaces would lead to slightly more readable code, eg around `:` or `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on your experience and intuition. You should read [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), which is the relevant specification for mailto URIs.

Some of the more obvious problems include:

- Header field names are case-insensitive (Sec 2, Paragraph 5).
- You are being a bit careless about `subject=` and `body=` by failing to ensuring that they are preceded by either a `?` or `&`.
- Strings are to be percent-encoded (Sec 5), which means that you should do percent-decoding.  If this code is to be run in a browser, you can use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).
- Spaces are supposed to be encoded as `%20` rather than as `+` (Sec 5).  The spec acknowledges that using `+` to mean <kbd>Space</kbd> does occur in practice, though.

In addition to the spec violations, I would say that the use of `false` rather than `null` to mean the absence of a property is weird.